# CSS Override Issue with Stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie at this so please excuse me if this doesn't make sense. In the #topbar2 section of this CSS Style-sheet I want the image NAFF_webtracker_logo.gif to appear. I believe I need to override just this section of the document since this is inherting from defaultstyle.css. This is in an application where I cannot edit defaultstylesheet.css. Is there a way I can override just this section to get my logo to appear? My coding seems correct but the image does not display.

Any help is appreciated.

Colin

```
/*
This file inherits all the styles from DefaultStyle.css
Please make sure that the following import link is present if you want to inherit default styles.
Any changes in fonts, colours, layout, etc. can be done via overriding CSS style elements after the import statement.

Good CSS guide is located at

http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/css/

*/
@import url(DefaultStyle.css);

/* put your changes below this comment */
body
{
 background-image: url(images/BG.gif);
 background-color: none;
 background-position: left top;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 color: #666666;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 11px;
}
#OuterContentPane 
{
    padding: 15px 30px 20px 30px;
    background: none;
    border-left: 0px solid;
    border-left-color: #ffffff;
    border-right: 0px solid;
    border-right-color: #ffffff;
}

#pagehead
{
    height: 204px;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #000000;
    background: #fff !important;
}

#topbar1
{
    color: #ffffff;
    /*background: none url(images/TopR.gif) no-repeat top left;*/
    height: 204px;
}

#topbar2
{
    color: #ffffff;
    background: url(images/NAFF_webtracker_logo.gif) no-repeat top left; 
    height: 204px;
}

.loginBox
{
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    background: #ddedf5 url(images/Boxag.gif) repeat-x top left;
    color: #666666;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 170px;
}

.loginBox input[type="text"], .loginBox input[type="password"]
{
    width: 169px;
}

.loginBox a, .loginBox a:visited
{
    color: #666666;
}

.loginBox a:hover
{
    color: #000000;
}

.LoginInstruction
{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    background: url(images/BoxBg.gif) repeat-x top left;
    color: #666666;
    padding: 15px;
    left: 264px;
    top: 220px;
    right: 16px;
    height: 322px;
}

#LoginStatusString
{
    text-align: right;
    color: #00A4E4;
    background: none;
    top: 113px;
    right: 0px;
}

#menu
{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 9pt;
    left: 231px;
    top: 149px;
    font-variant: normal;
    line-height: 26px;
    /*text-transform: uppercase;*/
}

#menu li 
{
    width: 124px;
    height: 26px;
    color: #00a4e4;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url(images/MButtH.gif) no-repeat top left;
    border: 0px solid;
}

#menu a, #menu a:visited
{
    color: #005596;
    background: url(images/MButt.gif) no-repeat top left;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

#menu a:hover  
{
    color: #00a4e4;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url(images/MButtH.gif) no-repeat top left;
}

.DetailsTable 
{ 
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.DetailsHeader
{
    color: #005596;
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 24px;
}

.DetailsHeader td
{
    background-image: url(images/MButt.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: top left;
}

.DetailsHeader a
{
    color: #005596;
    font-weight: Normal;
}

.DetailsHeader a:hover
{
    color: #000000;
}

a,
a:visited
{
    color: #666666;
    background: inherit;
}

a:hover
{
    color: #000000;
    background: inherit;
}

select, input
{
    font-size: 11px;
}

.ContentSection
{
    padding-left: 0px; 
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    background: none;
}

.DetailsCell
{
    color: #666666;
    background: none;
}

.DetailsAlternatingCell
{
    color: #666666;
    background: #ebf9fe;
}

.TimeLineLegend
{
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: none;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: solid 1px gray;
}

.TimeLineOverdue
{
    background: #ffb6c1;
    color: #000000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}

.TimeLinePending
{
    background: #FFFF00;
    color: #000000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}

.TimeLineCompleted
{
    background: #98fb98;
    color: #000000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}

.TimeLineCompletedLate
{
    background: #ffcc99;
    color: #000000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center
}

.TimeLineEstimate
{
    font-style: italic;
    color: #000000;
    background: inherit;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}

.Button.FilterStripGroup_none
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#pagefooter
{
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 8px;
    border-top: 0px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #000000;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 9px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    background: #dfdfe0;
}

#PageFooter a,
#PageFooter a:visited
{
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 10px;
}

#PageFooter a:hover
{
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 10px;
}

#LanguageSelection
{
    position:absolute;
    right: 10px;
}











html{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

#OuterContentPane{
    background-image: url('Images/Rectangle2.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 65px 30px 20px 30px !important;
}

#topbar1{
    background-size: cover;
    background-image:url('Images/header.jpg');
    background-position: -50px -45px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
}

#topbar2{
    display: none;
}

#loginBox, #QuickViewDetails{
    margin: 0 auto; 
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 440px
    max-width:100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 40px
}
#OuterContentPane select, #OuterContentPane input{
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 5px 6px;
}


.loginBox input[type="text"], .loginBox input[type="password"]{
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 5px 6px;
    background: #fff;
}

#SigninBtn, #FindBtn{
    padding: 5px 19px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #BF4646;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .8s; /* Safari */
    transition: background-color .8s;
}


#SigninBtn:hover, #FindBtn:hover{
    background-color:#09517B;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .8s; /* Safari */
    transition: background-color .8s;
}

#pagefooter{
    background-color:#333;
    margin: 0px;
    width:100%;
    min-height:75px;
    color:#fff;
}

#menu{
    width: 100%;
    left: 1px;
    top: 160px;

}
#menu, #menu *{
    background:#fff !important;
}

#menu > li{
    width: 14.2%;
    min-width: 95px;
}

#menu > li > ul{
    min-width: 200px;
    width: auto;
}

#ctl06_ctl01_ctl62_ctl00, #ctl06_ctl01_ctl61_ctl00{
    max-width: 110px;
}

@media(max-width:400){
    #topbar1{
        background-position: -40px -30px;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide a working fiddle so that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please only add the code relevant to the question, it's called [mcve]. You are also missing all the html, impossible to know what might be happening. And what do you need to overwrite that is in DefaultStyle.css?

Comment: Create a working fiddle so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Without you showing us the HTML code this CSS is applied to, this question is of course unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the !important keyword in CSS. This will override default styles.

```
#topbar2
{
    color: #ffffff;
    background: url(images/NAFF_webtracker_logo.gif) no-repeat top left !important; 
    height: 204px;
}
```

Comment: Using a selector with higher specificity is almost always preferable to using !important.

Comment: Agreed.  If the OP had shown html I would have answered using specificity.

Comment: Hi Brian. This did not make the image appear sadly. In fact none of the images in this css Stylesheet actually appear.  I do not have access to the HTML or the defaultstylesheet.css. This is an application called CargoWise that only allows editing of this particular stylesheet in order to place custom images overtop of a shipping tracker the application itself generates. 

When I put the !important; tag in it caused my top menu to lost formatting but not the image to appear. I greatly appreciate your suggestion and welcome anymore help !

Comment: you may want to carefully examine the path to the image.  Try 'inspect' in your browser to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Hi Brian, I don't think the logo is the issue. I am able to navigate to it in my web browser. It seems someone may have removed the original code that pointed to the logo in question in my Stylesheet. It should look like this

Comment: I want to replace the EDI Webtracker image with one of my own. Sorry I know this is likely not really what this forum is for. I will keep plugging away at it.

Comment: Brian is it helpful if I share the StyleSheet it is inheriting from ?

Comment: ColinC... That and your html would be helpful for using specificity.